# Having table <td> as checkbox, how to implement click and drag multiple selection on <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do have a code which changes checkbox state when `<td>` is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").click(function(e) {
    var chk = $(this).closest("td").find("input:checkbox").get(0);
    if (e.target != chk) {
      chk.checked = !chk.checked;
      if ($(this).closest("td").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked") == true) {
        $(this).closest("td").css("background-color", "red");
        console.log($(this).closest("td").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked"));
        console.log($(this).closest("td").find("input:checkbox").prop("value"));
      } else {
        $(this).closest("td").css("background-color", "white");
        console.log($(this).closest("label").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked"));
        console.log($(this).closest("label").find("input:checkbox").prop("value"));
      }
    }
  });


});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  /* display:none; */
}

td input:after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <!-- <form method="POST"> -->
  <table id='sample'>
    <tr>
      <th>Time\Date</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>07:30-08:00</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A1" type="checkbox">A1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B1" type="checkbox">B1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C1" type="checkbox">C1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D1" type="checkbox">D1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E1" type="checkbox">E1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F1" type="checkbox">F1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G1" type="checkbox">G1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:00-08:30</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A2" type="checkbox">A2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B2" type="checkbox">B2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C2" type="checkbox">C2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D2" type="checkbox">D2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E2" type="checkbox">E2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F2" type="checkbox">F2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G2" type="checkbox">G2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:30-09:00</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A3" type="checkbox">A3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B3" type="checkbox">B3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C3" type="checkbox">C3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D3" type="checkbox">D3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E3" type="checkbox">E3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F3" type="checkbox">F3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G3" type="checkbox">G3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- </form> -->
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I need to implement click and drag across multiple `<td>` which will also check the checkboxes. I do saw this [implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/3/), but I'm still can't get to have this work with my existing code.

Comment: Are you wanting to make multiple selection groups that may or may not overlap?

Comment: I'll combine both selection groups. Sort of I can both click each `<td>` or click and drag multiple `<td>` to check/uncheck them.

Comment: Instead of using the TD for your event, consider changing the size of each label to the size of your td ... clicking a label will automatically change the state of the associated checkbox. Maybe try this for the drag-to-select https://www.cssscript.com/select-multiple-elements-mouse-drag-selectables/

Comment: Though the problem on that implementation is that the active selection doesn't stick if the selection needs to be appended.

Comment: @kkshinichi do you mean like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/7tkveyfp/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reference is very helpfull, Hopefully my snippet can help you in any ways.. have a nice day :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;

  $("#sample input:checkbox").click(function() {
    return false;
  })
  $("#sample td:not(:first-child)")
    .mousedown(function() {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", isHighlighted);
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function() {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
        $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", isHighlighted);
      }
    })
    .bind("selectstart", function() {
      return false;
    })

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function() {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/58418830/having-table-td-as-checkbox-how-to-implement-click-and-drag-multiple-selectio#
input[type="checkbox"] {
  /* display:none; */
}

td input:after {
  background-color: red;
}

table td.highlighted {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <!-- <form method="POST"> -->
  <table id='sample'>
    <tr>
      <th>Time\Date</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>07:30-08:00</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A1" type="checkbox">A1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B1" type="checkbox">B1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C1" type="checkbox">C1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D1" type="checkbox">D1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E1" type="checkbox">E1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F1" type="checkbox">F1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G1" type="checkbox">G1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:00-08:30</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A2" type="checkbox">A2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B2" type="checkbox">B2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C2" type="checkbox">C2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D2" type="checkbox">D2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E2" type="checkbox">E2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F2" type="checkbox">F2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G2" type="checkbox">G2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:30-09:00</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A3" type="checkbox">A3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B3" type="checkbox">B3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C3" type="checkbox">C3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D3" type="checkbox">D3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E3" type="checkbox">E3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F3" type="checkbox">F3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G3" type="checkbox">G3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- </form> -->
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press mousedown we toggle a boolean to indicate that the mouse is down on. On mouseover a TD we check if the mouse is down and then check it. We prevent default behavior on mousedown to avoid text selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  // one click
  $('td').on( 'click', function(){
    var $checkbox =  $(this).find('input:checkbox')
    $checkbox.click()
     if ( $checkbox[0].checked ) {
       $checkbox.parent().css("background-color", "red");
     } else {
       $checkbox.parent().css("background-color", "white");
     }
  })

  var mouseDown = false;
  $('td').on('mousedown touchstart', function(event) {
  
    // Disable text selection
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // set boolean
    mouseDown = true;
  });
  $(window.document).on('mouseup touchend', function(event) {
   mouseDown = false;
 });
  
    $('td').on('mouseover', function(event) {
     if (mouseDown) {
       var $checkbox =  $(this).find('input:checkbox')
       if ( !$checkbox[0].checked ) {
         $checkbox.click()
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  /* display:none; */
}

td input:after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <!-- <form method="POST"> -->
  <table id='sample'>
    <tr>
      <th>Time\Date</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>07:30-08:00</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A1" type="checkbox">A1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B1" type="checkbox">B1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C1" type="checkbox">C1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D1" type="checkbox">D1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E1" type="checkbox">E1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F1" type="checkbox">F1</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G1" type="checkbox">G1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:00-08:30</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A2" type="checkbox">A2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B2" type="checkbox">B2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C2" type="checkbox">C2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D2" type="checkbox">D2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E2" type="checkbox">E2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F2" type="checkbox">F2</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G2" type="checkbox">G2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08:30-09:00</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="A3" type="checkbox">A3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="B3" type="checkbox">B3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="C3" type="checkbox">C3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="D3" type="checkbox">D3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="E3" type="checkbox">E3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="F3" type="checkbox">F3</td>
      <td><input name="checkbox" value="G3" type="checkbox">G3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- </form> -->
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Added another version with multi select based on start and end TD. Hopefully it helps you to find the right solution. https://jsfiddle.net/0o6f4wsc/2/